# Rouding discrepencies when data moves from UI to database (C# to SQL server, float? to float)

Tags: c#, sql-server, casting, rounding-error

I have a simple SQL Server stored procedure that updates my Utility Costs based on the Utility Id column provided as lookup.

When I call this stored procedure from C#, I am using the following code. The database is ending up with slightly different data than the actual cost.

For example, if the cost is 123, I might get 123.000000048204

When I put my breakpoint in code, I am finding that `U.CostMonthCal[1]` has the right value (123, for example). `U.CostMOnthCal[1]` is of type `float?`.

So I cast it as float. Code runs fine.

But 123 is converted to 123.00000000xxxx when it gets to the database.

It is doing that for all my columns, but you don't have to look at the entire code.

Just focus on the first column, `CostMonthCal1`. In the database, the column type is `float` (although I think I can probably convert it to real, and that would also save space... I am about to try that, to see if it fixes my problem).

```
    public static void UpdateUtilityCosts(clsUtility U)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ToString());
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand com;

            com = new SqlCommand("dbo.UpdateUtilityCosts", connection);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UtilityId", U.UtilityId));

            if (U.CostMonthCal[1] is null) { }  else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal1", (float) U.CostMonthCal[1])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[2] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal2", (float)U.CostMonthCal[2])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[3] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal3", (float)U.CostMonthCal[3])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[4] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal4", (float)U.CostMonthCal[4])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[5] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal5", (float)U.CostMonthCal[5])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[6] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal6", (float)U.CostMonthCal[6])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[7] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal7", (float)U.CostMonthCal[7])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[8] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal8", (float)U.CostMonthCal[8])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[9] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal9", (float)U.CostMonthCal[9])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[10] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal10", (float)U.CostMonthCal[10])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[11] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal11", (float)U.CostMonthCal[11])); }
            if (U.CostMonthCal[12] is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CostMonthCal12", (float)U.CostMonthCal[12])); }
            if (U.LineLossPct is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LineLossPct", (float)U.LineLossPct)); }
            if (U.GRT is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GRT", (float)U.GRT)); }
            if (U.POR is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@POR", (float)U.POR)); }

            if (U._12MonthCaps is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@12MonthCaps", (float)U._12MonthCaps)); }
            if (U._12MonthNits is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@12MonthNits", (float)U._12MonthNits)); }
            if (U._12MonthRate is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@12MonthRate", (float)U._12MonthRate)); }

            if (U.NonPolarCTA is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NonPolarCTA", (float)U.NonPolarCTA)); }
            if (U.PolarCTA is null) { } else { com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PolarCTA", (float)U.PolarCTA)); }

            if (com.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
                com.Connection.Open();

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string Msg;
            Msg = "Encountered unexpected program issue.  Please contact your program administator.  Error details...";
            Msg = Msg + System.Environment.NewLine;
            Msg = Msg + System.Environment.NewLine;
            Msg = Msg + e.ToString();
            Msg = Msg + System.Environment.NewLine;
            Msg = Msg + System.Environment.NewLine;
            Msg = Msg + e.Message;

            throw new Exception("Error Saving Cost Data.  Contact Program Administrator " + Msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection == null) { } else connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUtilityCosts] 
    (@UtilityId int = null, 
     @CostMonthCal1 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal2 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal3 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal4 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal5 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal6 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal7 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal8 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal9 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal10 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal11 float = null, 
     @CostMonthCal12 float = null,
     @LineLossPct float = null,
     @GRT float = null,
     @POR float = null,
     @12MonthCaps float = null,
     @12MonthNits float = null,
     @12MonthRate float = null,
     @NonPolarCTA float = null,
     @PolarCTA float = null)
as
begin
    update Utilities 
    set CostMonth1 = @CostMonthCal1, 
        CostMonth2 = @CostMonthCal2, 
        CostMonth3 = @CostMonthCal3, 
        CostMonth4 = @CostMonthCal4, 
        CostMonth5 = @CostMonthCal5, 
        CostMonth6 = @CostMonthCal6, 
        CostMonth7 = @CostMonthCal7, 
        CostMonth8 = @CostMonthCal8, 
        CostMonth9 = @CostMonthCal9, 
        CostMonth10 = @CostMonthCal10, 
        CostMonth11 = @CostMonthCal11, 
        CostMonth12 = @CostMonthCal12,
        LineLossPct = @LineLossPct,
        GRT = @GRT,
        POR = @POR,
        [12MonthCaps] = @12MonthCaps,
        [12MonthNits] = @12MonthNits,
        [12MonthRate] = @12MonthRate,
        NonPolarCTA = @NonPolarCTA,
        PolarCTA = @PolarCTA
    where UtilityId =  @UtilityId
end
GO
```

Comment: don't use float. Use numeric or decimal. FLOAT is an estimate.

Comment: you mean in my c# code, I shouldn't use float, and in my database, I can use any data type I want (float, real, etc.).  Right?

Comment: I think when I change database to real, it is working better, but I am encountering a different problem that I am working on, however, like KeithL mentioned, I think it might be better to change C# code and / or SQL server code with different type (not float).

Comment: The T-SQL double-precision `FLOAT` type is equivalent to C#'s `double`. `REAL` is single-precision and the equivalent of `float`. Per Keith, if possible, look into using `decimal` on the managed end and an appropriate `DECIMAL(<scale>, <precision>)` on the database end. This does not completely remove all surprises with rounding (mixing expressions with different scale and precision can still trip you up) but does make them more manageable.

Comment: Sorry about not being specific, but as Jeroen restated correctly. If you want precision (you usually do with money) you want to use a precise data type all the way through. float, real, double, single are not precise. decimal, money and numeric are all precise.

Comment: This is a problem with the language itself, even though there are workarounds (which I will accept as answer(s))  You shouldn't ever convert 123 to 123.00000324234.   Very odd, considering you are moving from less precise to more precise, and I gave you a whole number to begin with!  I'll pass this on to Microsoft.

Comment: KeithL, ok.  thanks.  I will try these data types instead....

Comment: Note that you do not pass a `SqlDbType` for your parameter either, meaning you are subject to at least two passes of conversion between types/precisions (and possibly more, if the x87 extended-precision format gets involved as an intermediate). This is almost certainly not a problem of C# itself; the ADO.NET classes and the SQL Server engine itself also get involved here. If you pass values in matching precisions and type your parameters explicitly, there shouldn't be any loss of precision, even with floating-point types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using decimal in code and any decimal (m, n) type in database seems to work, as per comments above.  But nobody has posted as an answer, so here i go....